# How can I disable the Toolbox in VisualStudio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, toolbox

The Loadingtime from the ToolBox is lagging my Environment. How can I disable the Toolbox in VisualStudio 2008.

I dont use the ToolBox, I work only in the XAML Code Mode.

Edit. I mean  the xamlcodeMode what i need , and I should like disable the desginMode.. sry

Comment: Just click the X at the top of the toolbox or use the View menu... is this a serious question?

Comment: yes this is a serious question... but i think u missunderstood me, if I open a view then should i like only the xamlcode and not the designmode, what load the Toolbox automatic

Answer (score 1):

WinForms has an automated load, so perhaps the XAML editor options has similar?

[How to stop Toolbox from loading controls out of every project in Solution](http://www.hightechtalks.com/visual-studio-net-ide/how-stop-toolbox-loading-controls-424042.html)

> Try going to the Tools, Options window, Windows Forms Designer section and
>   set AutoToolboxPopulate to false. [Carlos J. Quintero]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I need more information about what you really need, but I will recomend you that take a look to [XAMLPad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742398.aspx).

Good Luck.

Comment: the xamlpad show me 2 areas,the designmode and the xamlcode, i should like the designmode disable every time

Answer (score 0):

Press the X in the top right corner (of the toolbox window)?

Comment: Yes - you can close/move/collapse all helper windows in VS. And you layout should be stored.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @AUSTX_RJL The OP edited the question 11 minutes after I answered it.

Answer (score 0):

The Toolbox can still be slow when closed. I notice the statement in the STATUS BAR at the bottom sometimes stating "updating toolbox from assembly XXX" or something like that. And it is closed, not collapsed or hidden!

You can disable opening XAML in design view, which can speed up things a lot, but it does mean that you loose intellisense.

For me it was worth it at some point, and I don't need it always.

To disable the WPF designer mode for XAML, right-click the .xaml file, click "Open With", select XML editor (and consider SET AS DEFAULT).

If you set it as the DEFAULT way, you can always change your mind and open specific files in design view again by selecting OPEN WITH, and then the AUTOMATIC EDITOR at the top, or set it back as the DEFAULT mode.

You will notice that whenever you use the DESIGNER view again, things are A LOT slower for WPF XAML files.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just closing it?

**Ctrl + Alt + X** in design view (this shortcut could be different depending on your settings)

Comment: closing the toolbox does not get rid of the annoying "initializing toolbox" forced 3 minutes coffee break.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to seriously look into your machine if you have installed any unnecessary controls or lot of other 3rd party controls. Toolbox shouldn't be initialized always whenever you open VS. The **above suggested ways** (closing Toolbox and Exit Visual studio properly by choose File->Exit menu will save the layout of Visual studio) **are correct** and I don't think that there another way to turn off it.